# FontAwesome with Grails <g:actionSubmit

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons

I've been trying to add icons to my save, delete, etc. buttons. I have about five buttons using the `<g:actionSubmit>` tag to call an action in a controller to perform the corresponding functions. My problem is that FontAwesome and bootstrap's glyphicons require the `<i class="icon-***">` tag to be used like so:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i> Google
</a>
```

In grails this format of the tag in between the initial tag is not possible (at least with `actionSubmit`). The value attribute is the string that is displayed. Is there any work around for this? Keep in mind I still need to map the buttons action back to a controller which is why I've had issue using a straight `<button>` tag like what is recommended for bootstrap.

**UPDATE:**

I'm having a lot of problems using the current 2 answers. They both work for adding the icons, but I'm getting some nuisances that I'm having to hack a lot of things up to fix. I thought about another solution but am having some problems implementing it. I'd like to write my own tag lib using the base of the taglib as the actionSubmit tag lib below:

```
def actionSubmit = {attrs ->
    attrs.tagName = "actionSubmit"
    if (!attrs.value) {
        throwTagError("Tag [$attrs.tagName] is missing required attribute [value]")
    }

    // add action and value
    def value = attrs.remove('value')
    def action = attrs.action ? attrs.remove('action') : value

    out << "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"_action_${action}\" value=\"${value}\" "

    // process remaining attributes
    outputAttributes(attrs)

    // close tag
    out << '/>'
}
```

The only change I need to make is to give it the ability to take the

```
<i class="icon-ok"></i>
```

tag in between a:

```
<g:actionSubmit ...> </g:actionSubmit>
```

Does anyone have suggestions or for this implementation?

Comment: I suggest to create a post with the issue you are having, leave this post as is so people who have same issue can use it. Please specify your problem with the error or unexpected behaviors. Just saying `I'm getting some nuisances that I'm having to hack a lot of things up to fix` is not helping us helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the class name to remoteLink, which creates a link that uses Ajax to call a remote function and you can add your fontAwesome classes to it.

```
<g:remoteLink  class="btn icon-ok" action="index"  >
    click (without i tag)
</g:remoteLink>
```

or

```
<g:remoteLink  action="index" >
       <i class="btn icon-ok">click (with i tag) </i>
</g:remoteLink>
```

Both approaches should work. [image]

Comment: Updated my answer for Ajax calls, remoteLink should work as you wanted it.

Comment: This way also works except you have to do: 

    <g:remoteLink class="btn primary"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save</g:remoteLink>  it has to be in between the tags.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use actionSubmit, just use a `<button>` and provide the link/action properties like so:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">
  <i class="..."></i> Update
</button>
```

here's a more detailed example

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="_action_delete" value="Delete">
  <i class="..."></i> ${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}   
</button>
```

Note: actionSubmit passes the following input name/values for update, save and delete

```
name="_action_update" //update
name="_action_update" //save
name="_action_delete" //delete
```

so you would just need to do the same if you're app is dependent on them

Comment: Every time I try to imitate the tag lib I get an error at:

sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()

my code I tried is: 

<button type="submit" name="_action_save" class="btn" value="Save"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Save</button>