# Is there a way to make <g:link calls POST instead of GET?

Tags: security, grails, http-post

I'm using a

```
<g:link ...
```

tag for a button that I would like to send as POST instead of GET for security reasons.

Is there a way to do this? I cannot use

```
<g:actionSubmit
```

because I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's Glyphicons (i.e. I need to put the icon in between the tag, it can't go in a value attribute)

```
<g:link class="btn btn-success" action="someAction" id="class.id"> <i class="icon-ok"></i> Save </g:link>
```

So, I need a link that I can pass the ID as POST and includes a tag structure like:

```
<g:someTag ... > SOME LABEL </g:sometag>
```

Thanks for any help on this matter!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662383/fontawesome-with-grails-gactionsubmit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1.My suggestion is to use Ajax before the g:link it self handels the call to the action and controller

like:

```
<g:link class="btn btn-success"  id="class.id" onclick='UsingPost();'>SOME LABLE HERE </g:link>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function UsingPost(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{"model":${pleaseUseTheModelyouHaveLoaded}"}, 
        url:'${createLink(action: 'save')}',
        success:function(data,textStatus){
        jQuery('#success').html(data);},
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
        });
}
</script>
```

or refer to this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360606/grails-spring-security-core-ajax-authentication

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use  [g:remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html).  It defaults to using POST

```
<g:remoteLink action="someAction" id="${someObj.id}" update="saveStatus">Save</g:remoteLink>
```

Comment: note for anyone stumbling across this now, `remoteLink` is now deprecated and will be removed from a future release of Grails

Comment: And it seems that there is no redirecting if using remoteLink.