# Passing parameters in Link - Beginner

Tags: grails, groovy

The params i am passing through the `<link>` is too long in that case how can i send it

```
<td><g:link action="showresult" id="${r.id}" params="['dna': r.dnasequence,'order':r.order]">${fieldValue(bean: resultInstance, field: "patientId")}</g:link></td>
```

The value for `r.dnasequence` is more than 1000 characters long, So it all gets appends to the url.

How can i send it without having to append to the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a post request using g:link. It's better to use AJAX or remoteLink(deprecated).

[Is there a way to make <g:link calls POST instead of GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678748/is-there-a-way-to-make-glink-calls-post-instead-of-get)

Or

[FontAwesome with Grails <g:actionSubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662383/fontawesome-with-grails-gactionsubmit)

Comment: I am going through the examples on how to do this using remoteLink. But still have no clue. Can you please show me an example how to do so. I went through the link  http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html

Comment: In the first link, the 2nd answer has an example. Also, as remoteLink has been deprecated you are better off using jquery AJAX and not remoteLink.

Comment: According to that example what is `data:{"model":${pleaseUseTheModelyouHaveLoaded}"}, `. All what i want to pass is a bunch of String characters as shown in the above post.